# Setting up WebLogic for an IntelliJ Java Web Application Project

Tags: networking, java, intellij-idea

I'm getting the error

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:7001
```

when I try to configure WebLogic for my Java web app in IntelliJ. Note that I am not creating a project from scratch and trying to configure WebLogic for an already-written app on another machine.

I have successfully installed WebLogic Server
and created a "base_domain" for it and I can connect
to `http:\\hostname:port\console` to see the admin settings. The error mentioned above happens only when trying to configure in IntelliJ. It only occurs AFTER I "run" the server on IntelliJ and it asks me to "Enter username to boot WebLogic server:". I type the correct username that I defined for my base_domain before, but then it stops with the mentioned error and the log is showing this:

```
Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.
Disconnected from server
```

Comment: You’ve obscured the server information you are actually entering. There is a big gap between what `localhost:7001` and what `http://hostname:port/console` might be. If you want help with how to connect these two things together you’ll have to not hide the information specifically related to connecting the two together. And be specific. Show exactly what you are entering in IntelliJ and clarify if the two systems are running on the same server/computer. If the answer was obvious you wouldn’t be here asking, so don’t make us guess.

Comment: I’m having a little difficulty understanding your second sentence (the one that begins “Note”).   It might be clearer if you broke it into two separate sentences.